# Dead battery or?

Tags: battery

Jump started dead battery, took car out for test drive and to charge up battery, lost power without any warnings while driving, no lights came on just total power loss. Had to jump start car again cause no power. Started to drive home and again no warnings car went dead. Jump started again and finally got home safe and sound. Ran car for awhile, turned off car and again dead battery

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! Have you checked the output of the alternator while the engine is running? Check the voltage at the battery before starting and after running. If there isn't much difference, take the alternator in to a parts store and have it checked for proper operation.

Answer (score 1):

This points to one of two things, one indeed being a dead battery.  The other potential problem is that the alternator isn't producing any power to charge the electrical system.  If you have a battery charger, try charging the battery overnight and see if it's still dead after that.  Alternatively, have the output of the alternator tested to ensure it's producing charge.

If it were mine, I'd switch the battery with a known good spare but I do have a spare battery available so it would be a no-cost option for me.  If you don't have a battery, I'd take the car somewhere local that can test the output of the alternator first to avoid the expense of replacing a battery if it wasn't needed.  Most cars, once just started, with a healthy alternator ought to continue to run although most failed alternators will illuminate a warning light on the dashboard.